# PowerBi refreshing issue (MySQL)

Tags: powerbi, refresh

I`ve got a strange problem with refreshing data. I`m using PowerBi to connect GCP (MySQL).
The same query executed in mysql workbench is finished in 2-3 seconds, but the same query shared in cloud is timeouting almost always.

90% of executing time in PowerBi is taken by "waiting for server..." step.

1. Fitting queries
2. Changing setting with IT support

Actually server parameters are upgraded and problem is not existing, but this not solving problem why the same query is execiuted fast on workbench but takes much time in cloud.

Comment: PBI can query fold meaning any additional steps in Power Query can be sent back to the source. Do a test of a simple query with no additional steps after as a test. Or provide your power query script in your question.

Comment: can you post the steps of data transformation in advance editor?

Comment: there is only one step in advanced editor:

let
    Źródło = MySQL.Database("IP", "schema", [ReturnSingleDatabase=true, Query=" select * from TABLE where date  >= now() - interval 100 day#(lf)", CreateNavigationProperties=false]),
    #"Zmieniono typ" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Źródło,{{"visit_at", type date}, {"poz", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Zmieniono typ"

Comment: @SamNseir after testing query with no extra steps i have to say that there is no big difference on time waiting for server. my query is simple (calculations are written in DAX), but there is lots of rows (for 100 days in query its around 800k rows). maybe there is setup in PowerBi which can be changed? meanwhile i am searching for any informations on microsoft forum (community.fabric.microsoft.com). unfortunatelly i am still stuck.